# The layout.jade is not working, why?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

This is my configure file:
The layout.jade does not seem to be working. But the jade is working. I used Chrome to check, and am sure that the layout HTML is not loaded into the page.

```
module.exports = function(app, express, mongoose){
    var config=this

    app.configure(function (){
        app.set('views',__dirname+'/views')
        app.set('view engine','jade')
        app.set('view options', {layout:true})

        app.use(express.bodyParser())
        app.use(express.methodOverride())
        app.use(express.cookieParser())
        app.use(express.session({secret: 'topsecret',store: new express.session.MemoryStore}))
        app.use(express.static(app.path.join(app.application_root,"public")))
        app.use(express.errorHandler({dumpExceptions:true,showStack:true}))
        app.use(express.bodyParser({keepExtensions: true, uploadDir:"./public/uploads"}))
        app.use(app.router)
    })

    /*DB part:*/
    app.mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dio_database')

    return config
}
```

The render command:

```
app.get('/items/:id',function(req,res){
    models.ItemModel.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).exec(function(err,item){
        if (!err){
            res.render('item.jade',item)
        } else
            return console.log(err)
    })
})
```

My layout.jade, quite simple:

```
!!!
doctype 5
html
    head
        title "Dio"
        link(rel='icon', href='favicon.ico', type='image/x-icon')
        link(rel='shortcut', href='favicon.ico', type='image/x-icon')
        link(rel="shortcut", href="favicon.ico", type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon")
        link(rel="icon", href="favicon.ico", type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon")

        script(src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js")
        script(src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js")
        script(src="./javascripts/underscore-min.js")
        script(src="./javascripts/backbone-min.js")

        link(rel='stylesheet', href='./css/main.css', type="text/css", media="screen")
    body
        div#topbar Dio--where shitty thing happens
        div#main!= body
            footer
                p
                    | Node.js MVC template by XXX
```

And the following is my npm list:

```
├─┬ bcrypt@0.7.3
│ └── bindings@1.0.0
├─┬ express@3.0.3
│ ├── commander@0.6.1
│ ├─┬ connect@2.7.0
│ │ ├── bytes@0.1.0
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11
│ │ ├── pause@0.0.1
│ │ └── qs@0.5.1
│ ├── cookie@0.0.5
│ ├── cookie-signature@0.0.1
│ ├── crc@0.2.0
│ ├── debug@0.7.0
│ ├── fresh@0.1.0
│ ├── methods@0.0.1
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.3
│ ├── range-parser@0.0.4
│ └─┬ send@0.1.0
│   └── mime@1.2.6
├── fs@0.0.0
├── imagemagick@0.1.3
├─┬ jade@0.27.7
│ ├── coffee-script@1.4.0
│ ├── commander@0.6.1
│ └── mkdirp@0.3.4
├─┬ mongodb@1.2.2
│ └── bson@0.1.5
├─┬ mongoose@3.4.0
│ ├── hooks@0.2.1
│ ├─┬ mongodb@1.1.11
│ │ └── bson@0.1.5
│ ├── ms@0.1.0
│ └── sliced@0.0.3
├─┬ node-static@0.6.5 extraneous
│ ├── colors@0.6.0-1
│ └─┬ optimist@0.3.5
│   └── wordwrap@0.0.2
└── path@0.4.9
```

Comment: OK, I think the problem is the new jade no longer supports layout, but supports block and extends. I am just wondering is this thing so minor  that few people raised it clearly? Took me 2 hours to figure it out.

Comment: Express3 no longer supports layout

Comment: Where is your item.jade template? Also, could you update your question with the error output if there is any?... Also, check out the way you are passing item as a local var to the template.... Shouldnt it be {item: item}??? Maybe you should try a simpler layout and item template rendering in order to test your case...

Comment: Express middlewares should always return a response... In your else clause you are returning an undefined ( from console.log...)

Comment: @CristianDouce it did not generate any error. As I said and agreed with Jonathan Ong. Express 3 no longer supports layout.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually the reason for such problem is quite simple:
Express 3 no longer supports layout..But do not be sad. Actually Express 3 begins to adopt a more natural and easier way, which is called **block/extends**. 
The basic usage should be like this:

```
// In layout file: layout.jade
html 
    head
        title XXX
        block scripts
    body
        block content
        block footer


// in a extended file, for example index.jade:
extends layout
block scripts
    //write javascript part
block content
    // write content
block footer
    // write the footer
```

It actually becomes easier and more flexible. Glad to get it finally. But it took me more than 2 hours.

I am just wondering why so few people mentioned this change more clearly and openly. Hope this post can help some people like me.

Comment: Thanks and a quick note to make sure you indent your block-code in the extended file as @Yitong has done with the comments.

Comment: Wish that I could give you more than one vote. This solution and the comment above, finally helped me solve why my extended file was not displaying. Thank you!