# Logo sign next to title in the tab of browser

Tags: html, css, pug

Could you please tell what do I need to do in my html/css code to display logo next to the title in the tab of of browser window?

My Current code is (jade template)

```
!!!
html
  head
    title= 'my website title'
  body!= body
```

Comment: We'll need more information than that, and that doesn't look like any html I've ever seen.  What are you using this in?

Comment: What on earth is that 'code' meant to be?

Comment: Now that you know that that "thing" is commonly named favicon you should be able to quickly find what you're looking for - have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783687/the-layout-jade-is-not-working-why (not about the same topic, but there a jade code fragment that uses a favicon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a *favicon*, and there are plenty of tutorials to do exactly that online, including this one by the authorities:

http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

It's also worth mentioning that the code you have there is not HTML, it looks like a templating language called Jade. Jade can be used to *generate* HTML, but it shouldn't be confused with the actual language.

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png" type="image/png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.example.com/favicon.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to the [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

It's simply a file in the web root of your site, called *favicon.ico*. Browsers pick it up automatically.

Although there are different ways to implement it. Also refer to the other answers on this post.